# Renting car in Mexico, are there any hidden fees on the online fares?

Tags: car-rentals, mexico, fees-and-charges

I am considering to rent a car in México and found some reasonable fares online.

I saw a couple of videos though that mentioned that to those prices a fee was added when picking the car. Apparently the insurance (that's what I understood, but it can be something else)  is not included yet.

Is that the case? Are there hidden fees that I should be aware of before renting online?

Comment: There could be a myriad of extra fees depending on your circumstances eg Collision Damage Waiver, additional driver(s), excess mileage, refuelling before returning the vehicle

Comment: Generally, the insurance you will be offered is the minimum legal cover, so third party only. If so it is prudent to pay extra (and it can be quite a lot extra) for comprehensive cover. At one airport on a small island, a well-known franchise rental charged me for a full tank of fuel and told me to bring the car back empty. Wonderful scam on a captive customer.

Comment: When I rented in Mexico all was included. They did give me a smaller car than promised though. Of course YMMV.